# Drupal Node Hierarchy and Views Arguments

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views

I'm building a Drupal website that has a simple hierarchical structure created using the Node Hierarchy module:

-Personal Training
-Boot Camps
--Locations
--Instructors

Each parent menu item has at least two 'price tag' nodes associated with it (through a node reference CCK field). I'm trying to create a views block that shows on all parent and child pages but only shows the price tags associated with the parent menu item.

I've tried various combinations of views relationships and arguments with no luck other than getting the correct price tags on the parent pages but not on their children. I've also tried adding the price tag nodes as children of the parent node and using the 'Parent node ID' argument supplied to views by the Node Hierarchy Module.

Am I structuring things wrong or is there some setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference I ended up having to add a node reference to all the pages I wanted to show the price tags on rather than just the parent. In some ways this gives more flexibility but it's not as 'nice' as only having to reference the parent node.